# Convert image to true black and white

Tags: skiasharp

To print an image on a non-colour printer I need to convert the image to a single colour format.  Ive managed to convert to Gray8 using the ColorFilter example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/color-filters  but gray scale is not the same as black and white.  When it prints it gets dithered by the printer because the image contains colour channels.

There doesnt seem to be any ColorType or simple way to do this with SkiaSharp.  Am I missing something?

We are printing by generating an XPS.. not sure how relevant that is.